# Make bootstrap tabs change with carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have been asked to make the active carousel picture change the bootstrap tabs to have the active class as well. I'm not sure how to do this and have tried capturing the active first tab, then i need to iterate over them but not sure how to do this in time with the slider of the carousel.
This is where I am:

```
var activeTab = $('.tabpanel ul li.active');
$('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
    activeTab.next.addClass('.active');

});
```

The code just errors in the console.

Answer (score 1):

next syntax have parenthesis. you missed parenthesis

```
 activeTab.next().addClass('.active');
```

Comment: Of course this won't work when it reaches the last tab.

Comment: @DavidG that is not a question ok

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment.

Comment: The Op ask there is error in console that why i found the issue next. he missed the parenthesis in the code. i point out that mistake\

Comment: Yes it doesn't do what I wanted it to do. I want the tab to have active on it and show the tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would achieve it. First get the [current index](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/2404#issuecomment-4589229) in the carousel, then use that to determine which tab to show. Untested code, but should be enough:

```
$('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
    //var index = $('.carousel .active').index('.carousel .item');
    var carouselData = $(this).data('bs.carousel');
    var index = carouselData.getActiveIndex();
    var activeTab = $('.tabpanel ul li.active');
    activeTab.removeClass('.active');
    var tabs = $('.tabpanel ul li');
    tabs[index].addClass('.active');
});
```

Comment: It doesn't get the index of the item its always -1 so I tried adding it +1 to .index('.carousel .item') and it always alerts 0

Comment: undefined is not a function